# Master Detail Page in Ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Master Details Page in Ios,now i need to show some value in details page when button in master page is clicked.Can some one help me to achieve it.

```
public class StoresTabletPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public StoresTabletPage()
    {
        Title = "Stores";           
        Detail = new ContentPage
        {
            IsVisible = true,
            MinimumWidthRequest = 100,

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children =
                {
                    new Label { Text = "Label1", FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)) }
                }
            }
        };
        Master = new ContentPage
        {
            MinimumWidthRequest = 500,
            Title = "string",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children =
                {
                    new Button{ Text = "1", FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button)) }
                }
            }
        };
```

So,when button is clicked in master page it should show label1 in detail page.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Command on button and Command Parameter to pass the value you want to show on details page

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)